# Updating values using case on the same field

Tags: mysql

I am trying this update statement using a case in MySQL, but It does not change any values.

The query does not give any errors, but there are 0 affected rows.

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `type` = (
    CASE
        WHEN `type` = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN `type` = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN `type` = 3 THEN 19
        WHEN `type` = 4 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 5 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 6 THEN 81
        WHEN `type` = 7 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 8 THEN 22
        WHEN `type` = 9 THEN 21
        WHEN `type` = 10 THEN 78
        WHEN `type` = 11 THEN 80
        WHEN `type` = 12 THEN 79
    END)
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Anyone know how I can fix this.

Comment: If use select statement, will return any records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `type` after the `Case`.

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `type` = 
    CASE `type`
        WHEN  1 THEN 1
        WHEN  2 THEN 2
        WHEN  3 THEN 19
        WHEN  4 THEN null
        WHEN  5 THEN null
        WHEN  6 THEN 81
        WHEN  7 THEN null
        WHEN  8 THEN 22
        WHEN  9 THEN 21
        WHEN  10 THEN 78
        WHEN  11 THEN 80
        WHEN  12 THEN 79
    END
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This did not help, still 0 affected rows. All the values are still the same.

Comment: even if you removed the `parethesis`?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE test 
SET `password` = (
CASE
    WHEN `password` = 1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN `password` = 2 THEN 'two'
    WHEN `password` = 3 THEN 'three'
    WHEN `password` = 4 THEN null
    WHEN `password` = 5 THEN null
    WHEN `password` = 6 THEN 81
    WHEN `password` = 7 THEN null
END)
where userindex=1
```

working perfectly fine for me .I manuplated it to suite my test data ..kindly remanuplate values and try again.

also check if you have any user with not null user_id

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine. Suggest to use a select to try if will return any records.

```
SELECT *, CASE
        WHEN `type` = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN `type` = 2 THEN 2
        WHEN `type` = 3 THEN 19
        WHEN `type` = 4 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 5 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 6 THEN 81
        WHEN `type` = 7 THEN null
        WHEN `type` = 8 THEN 22
        WHEN `type` = 9 THEN 21
        WHEN `type` = 10 THEN 78
        WHEN `type` = 11 THEN 80
        WHEN `type` = 12 THEN 79
    END as test 
FROM `tablename` WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
```